# Uipagecontrol animation

Tags: animation, ios5, uipagecontrol

I have customized the page control where I am using the scrollview , which consists of 3 pages. the dots has been customized.

but while swiping the page , can I change the animation to be quick dissolve animation. Does it look good for page control ?

please suggest which animation is good for paging ?

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling the views left and right, the usual behaviour, is the best way to switch between views in a page control container.

Yes, you *could* change the animation, but don't. Using a dissolve is just going to confuse your users.